# secure connections between vps servers

Tags: vps, tunneling

I have four VPS servers. Two of them are replicated glusterfs server and the other two are glusterfs clients.

What I want to do is to encrypt all communications between glusterfs servers and between servers and clients. My question is, what is popular solution fot this?

I am considering openvpn and openswan and wondering how stable they are. At least my windows openvpn client often become unresponsive.

Comment: The stability depends on network condition, sometimes server load too. Are the two machine on the same network / data center?

Comment: possibly same, possibly different. I have no control over where the server I bought is placed.

Comment: How do you have no control over where you bought a server?

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN is one of the best Open Source and free software available out there for the requirement you are looking for.

Regarding the stability, I have been using openvpn from long time, and leaving a couple of issue here and there, which I can easily take care of by some scripting, I found it pretty stable and trust worthy.

Also, as John said, it does too depend on the network connection, and the load on the server, but I am sure that will effect everything in this network world, so you have to take care of that anyways.